# Erro ao agrupar por mês com INNER join usando Postgres

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, administração-postgresql

Bom dia!

Estou tentando agrupar minha tabela por mês porém não está funcionando..

Estou utilizando essa query:

```
SELECT "Boleto"."id", 
sum("valor_parcela") AS "volume_operado", 
sum("spread") AS "spread", 
sum("valor_pago") AS "liquidacoes", 
date_trunc('month', "Boleto"."criado_em") AS "criado_em", 
"boleto_taxa"."id" AS "boleto_taxa.id", 
"boleto_taxa"."valor" AS "boleto_taxa.valor" 
FROM "tb_boletos" AS "Boleto" 
INNER JOIN "tb_boletos_taxa" AS "boleto_taxa" 
ON "Boleto"."id" = "boleto_taxa"."boleto_id" 
AND "boleto_taxa"."taxa_id" = 1 
WHERE "Boleto"."operado" = true 
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "Boleto"."criado_em"), "Boleto"."id", "boleto_taxa"."id"
```

Que me retorna esse resultado:

```
id          | volume_operado | spread          | liquidacoes    | criado_em      | boleto_taxa_id |          
1           | 200.00         | 40.00           | 5.00           | 2020-05-28     |  1             |
2           | 300.00         | 50.00           | 6.00           | 2020-05-28     |  2             |
```

Sendo que possuo 3 registros, sendo que tenho 3 registros(2 do mes de maio) e ele não está agrupando esses dois registros do mês de meio devido que tive que colocar esses dados : "Boleto"."id", "boleto_taxa"."id" senão o postgres da erro que GROUP by quando faço o INNER JOIN

A questão que acredito que seja é: Group by quando eu n faço o INNER join ele me retornar separado por mês certinho mas quando eu faço, ele da erro no GROUP BY na tabela "boleto_taxa"."id".

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: No PostgreSQL por definição os campos do select que não são uma função de agregação devem estar em sua cláusula GROUP BY. Talvez você tenha que repensar sua construção da expressão SQL.

Comment: @Matheus Lopes: Os campos `valor_parcela`, `spread` e `valor_pago` pertecem a quais tabelas? Explique o campo `taxa_id`, ele faz parte da tabela `tb_boletos_taxa`? Ele se trata de uma chave estrangeira ?